# react-komposer, composer functions that depend on prop provided by other composer functions

Tags: meteor, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Hello I'm trying to compose composer functions that depends on props provided by other composer functions.

This one **provides** prop called `a`.

```
import {useDeps, composeWithTracker, composeAll} from 'mantra-core';
import Component from '../components/component';

export const composerA = ({context, _id}, onData) => {
  const {Meteor,Collections} = context();
  const query = {_id};
  if (Meteor.subscribe('a', query).ready()) {
    const a = Collections.A.findOne(query);
    onData(null,{a});
  }
};
```

This one **depends** on prop called `a`.

```
// depends on `prop` named `a` which is provided  by `composerA`
export const composerB = ({context, a}, onData) => {
  const {Meteor,Collections} = contex();
  if(a){
    const query = {a_id : a._id};
    if (Meteor.subscribe('b', query).ready()) {
      const bs = Collections.B.find(query);
      onData(null,{bs});
    }
  }
};
```

When there's no dependency, it works fine.

```
export const ThisWorks = compoaseAll(
  composeWithTracker(composerA),
  // some other composer function without dependency 
  composeWithTracker(composerWithoutDependency)
)(Component);
```

But when I compose it with composerB which depends on A it loads/waits forever.

```
export const ThisLoadsForever = composeAll(
  composeWithTracker(composerA),
  composeWithTracker(composerB)
)(Component);
```

I have also tried doing it like this

```
export const temp = composeAll(
  composeWithTracker(composerA)
)(Component);
export const StillLoadsForever = composeAll(
  composeWithTracker(composerB)
)(temp);
```

I suspect that prop `a` never becomes available or not null to `composerB`, hence waiting/loading forever.
How do I fix this? Or is there other way to compose composers with dependency?

PS: I'm using mantra-js.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`composeAll` composes the functions from right to left. If you depend on a prop from componentA in componentB you need to put componentB above componentA:

`export const ThisLoadsForever = composeAll(
  composeWithTracker(composerB),
  composeWithTracker(composerA)
)(Component);`